# Currying or closure

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

Hello I'm doing a javascript coding interview, to prepare for an upcoming one.
i had a question that confused me a bit. The question is as follow :

What concept is being illustrated below ?

```
function makeAdder(x) {
  return function (y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}

var addFive = makeAdder(5);
console.log(addFive(3));
```

There were 4 answers to pick from and then there's :
Currying and
Closure

I thought both of these were right. I ended up picking currying, but i really thought this is illustrating closures as well? Could you explain why this is not illustrating closures?

Comment: _"Could you explain why this is not illustrating closures?"_ - it is also related to closures. Function returned by the `makeAdder` function has a _closure_ over the parameter `x`.

Comment: This should be both `currying` and `closure`...

Comment: This same example is used to explain closures in the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: @decpk i agree, but apparently the only right answer is currying : https://github.com/Ebazhanov/linkedin-skill-assessments-quizzes/blob/master/javascript/javascript-quiz.md

Comment: To be on the safe side, I'd pick "closure". Sure, `makeAdder` is a *curried* version of `+`, but for actual "currying" going on I'd expect to see `makeAdder = curry((x, y) => x+y)`.

Answer (score -1):

Currying is always a syntax Sugar for closures.It doesn’t call a function. It just transforms it.

For Your above case It's Just Closures because you are taking another variable which stores inner function and executing differently
. Like addFive is inner function which is being invoked later.

If you want to to currying it would be like the below example i have created.
Currying is the concept of closure, due to its leading exection braces which help inner function executions at same times. So here you don't have to take another variable to store for calling the inner function.

By definition, currying should convert sum(a, b, c) into sum(a)(b)(c).

```js
function makeAdder(x) {
  return function (y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}


console.log(makeAdder(5)(3));
```

Comment: That's the confusing part apparently the right answer is currying https://github.com/Ebazhanov/linkedin-skill-assessments-quizzes/blob/master/javascript/javascript-quiz.md

Comment: "*Currying is always a syntax Sugar for closures.*" I disagree. On multiple accounts. First of all, it's not "syntax sugar". It implies it's just specific syntax that's introduced to make something easier. But it's not special syntax. Second, I don't think it's always implemented *as* a closure. You can have `add = curry((x, y) => x + y)`  then that will give you a curried function. Depending on the implementation of `curry`, it might or might not rely on closure behaviour.

Comment: @kevin those question seem a bit garbage. I got to Q9 and the answer is straight up wrong. The rest didn't have wrong answers but weren't great, either. Q7 has the wrong code associated with it and the answers don't actually make sense related to it. Q5 shows up twice. And arguably has a second correct answer. Q9 does not have any correct answers. Any and all functions in JS are closures. There isn't a special mechanism that makes them one. Functions that don't use variables from a parent scope are *uninteresting closures* but still ones.

Comment: @kevin oh, and Q8 has an answer that is technically true but probably shouldn't be used. There are better ways to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: lol and they're all made by LinkedIn... That's not right. I guess i'll try something else @VLAZ

Comment: @VLAZ referring to your 2nd comment, can you give an example implementation of `curry` function that doesn't rely on closure(s)? I can't think of a curried function that doesn't relies on closure(s).

Comment: @Yousaf [here you go](https://jsbin.com/lawizucoju/1/edit?js,console). I modified [this implementation](https://javascript.info/currying-partials#advanced-curry-implementation) (first one in the section I link to) so instead of accessing `args` from its parent scope, does partial application via `.bind()`.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for taking the time to create this demo , really appreciate it. Correct me if I am wrong but isn't your demo also relying on the closure? Function invocation expression (`func.apply(this, args`) inside the `if` statement inside `curried` function uses `func` from the outer `curry` function.

Comment: @Yousaf you're right, I missed that `func` is also coming from the parent scope. So, I decided to be less lazy and [re-wrote the curry function instead of slightly modifying it](https://jsbin.com/xonirodizu/1/edit?js,console). Now there are no inner functions that access outer scope.

Comment: @VLAZ code in the new demo is much more readable BUT the new function returned by `curry.bind(null, func, ...args)` has a closure over `func` and `args`?!

Comment: @Yousaf it does not close over them. `.bind()` defines a new function and partially applies the arguments, however the function is not defined in the same scope, thus does not close over `func` and `args`. Consider [this quick example](https://jsbin.com/buyumapuqe/1/edit?js,console) the function created by `b` does not close over `foo`. Because it's created in a separate scope. Similarly, `.bind()` will not close over `func` because it's not created in the same scope as well. If we look this at technical level, `.bind()` does *not* close over anything.

Comment: @Yousaf [A bound function exotic object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-internal-slots-of-bound-function-exotic-objects) only keeps track of the bound function, `this`, and any partially allocated arguments. Compare with  [a regular function](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-internal-slots-of-ecmascript-function-objects) which does keep the scope it was defined in as the internal slot `[[Environment]]`. So, 1. `.bind()` doesn't form closures 2. Even if it did, it wouldn't close over anything in `curry`.

Comment: @VLAZ ah yes! you are absolutely right. Your last comment got me thinking about the function created by `.bind()` and I agree, its not a closure. Again, thank you!